# What font does bitly use in their logo?

Tags: fonts, font-identification

What font is used in this logo?

[image: bitly logo]

*Editor's note: while this was their logo at the time this question was written, bit.ly have since adopted a [new logo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPb66.png).*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Whatthefont.com](http://whatthefont.com) says FF Netto OT-Bold

You can find it [here](http://www.fontshop.com/fonts/downloads/fontfont/ff_netto_ot/)

It's kinda expensive... $215 or $54

 I suggest something like Arial Rounder Narrow if you don't insist on perfect match :)

Good Luck!

Comment: $54 for the font, $215 for the family. Sample URL: http://www.fontshop.com/fonts/singles/fontfont/ff_netto_ot_bold/?&sample_text=bit.ly&sample_size=96&acs_pt=32&update=0

Comment: $54's still expensive for a font... Is it not? (Without a client backing your project or some source of funding.)

Comment: Everything's relative, and the OP doesn't give any background about who might be paying.